# How to find the likelihood of a uniform random variable with support of length 1, but where we don't know where it starts.

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

[image: The Question]

It is said for the above question the answer is **Option A)** A horizontal line between $x_1$  and $x_1-1$.

I am unable to understand **how the likelihood is being expressed in terms of $x_1$** rather than it being constant and  equal to one for $\theta < x_1 ≤ \theta+1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

We're looking for $\theta$ given the sample data $x_1$ and given the parameterization of the distribution, all the possible/likely candidates for $\theta$ are at the interval $(x_1-1, x_1)$

So the sample $x_1$ can only come from this interval
$$\theta<x_1<\theta+1$$
Which is just two inequalities

- $$\theta<x_1$$
- $$x_1<\theta+1\Rightarrow x_1-1<\theta$$

Now just rearranging the inequalities  to isolate $\theta$ we would have
$$x_1-1<\theta<x_1$$

Intuition example:

Say the actual value of $\theta$ is $3.5$. So your true uniform distribution is on the interval $(\theta,\theta+1)=(3.5,4.5)$ (in red).

Suppose you did not know this true $\theta$ and the only information you have is a sample from the true distribution and suppose this sample is $4$ (in blue).

Your best bet to guess the starting point of the true distribution is to look at the *starting* direction which is to the left of the sample point. You no longer care about the *end* point because the *"length of one"* restriction makes it so that knowing the *start* already gives *"sufficient"* information about the *end* point.

So $(x_1-1,x_1)$ captures the true value of $\theta$. Thinking of extreme cases, $x_1$ might be the true end point but still the interval $(x_1-1,x_1)$ would capture the true value of $\theta$.

[image]

In a more advance but related topic, this restricted distribution is considered to belong to a *curve exponential family* where in the parameter space is restricted wherein knowing one parameter already fixes the value of the other parameters of the distribution, hence the only need to guess a single parameter.

Comment: I understood the part that We're looking for θ given the sample data x1. Can you please explain  how all the possible/likely candidates for θ are at the interval (x1−1,x1)

Comment: @RishavDhariwal Added some examples.

Comment: Thanks @Derf this really made it clear especially the intuition example. I couldn't get that this restricted distribution is considered to belong to a curve exponential family, but the intuition example made it clear. Thank again